# How do I asynchronously process Stream events and await all async processing is done in dart?

Tags: dart, asynchronous

I have an image that I want to scale down to 3 different resolutions and upload to Cloud Storage.

I have a `Stream<LocalResource> ImageResizer` class that scales down the original image using `compute()` and returns them as a Stream.

Now I want to process each event like so (simplified):

```dart
List<CloudResource> cloudResources = [];
await for (final resource in ImageResizer(source: file)) {
  final id = await cloudStorage.upload(resource);
  final url = await cloudStorage.getDownloadableLinkFor(id);
  cloudResources.add(CloudResource(id: id, url: url);
}
await database.saveAsset(resources: cloudResources);
```

This simple implementation works, but I want it to work concurrently, as  `ImageResizer` does not need to wait for the upload to complete to yield another value and everything can be processed out-of-order.

I tried several approaches using `Stream.listen()`, `Stream.mapAsync()` and `await Stream.pipe()`, using which I could achieve concurrency, but **I failed to figure out how to await the point when all upload tasks are done and `cloudResources` can be saved.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your code a bit so that the parts that you want to be potentially concurrent are in a separate asynchronous function, call that function for each element of the `Stream`, collect the resulting `Future`s, and use `Future.wait` to wait for them all to complete.  For example:

```dart
List<CloudResource> cloudResources = [];

Future<void> upload(CloudResource resource) async {
  final id = await cloudStorage.upload(resource);
  final url = await cloudStorage.getDownloadableLinkFor(id);
  cloudResources.add(CloudResource(id: id, url: url);
}

await Future.wait([
  await for (final resource in ImageResizer(source: file)
    upload(resource),
]);
await database.saveAsset(resources: cloudResources);
```

Comment: Smart, thanks! For anyone looking into this, I perfected the final solution so that `upload()` returns `Future<CloudResource>`, then in `await for` I save a List of these Futures and finally in a separate loop I await these Futures and save the result. This way `cloudResources` do not need to be defined globally.

Answer (score 0):

I removed your specific classes, but save the main idea. This code creates 3 isolates to handle data concurrently.

```dart
Stream<String> imageResizer(String startWith) async* {
  yield '$startWith 1';
  yield '$startWith 2';
  yield '$startWith 3';
}

Future<int> upload(String link) async {
  print('upload for $link');
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

  return link.hashCode;
}

Future<String> getDownloadableLinkFor(int id) async {
  print('getDownloadableLinkFor for $id');

  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

  return ':hash_$id';
}

Future<String> _uploadResource(String resource) async {
  print('_uploadResource for $resource');

  final id = await upload(resource);
  final url = await getDownloadableLinkFor(id);

  return '$resource, $id, $url';
}
```

and code to call

```dart
child: TextButton(
            child: Text(gettext("Run example")),
            onPressed: () async {
              final resolutions = await imageResizer('test').toList();
              final tasks = resolutions.map((e) => compute(_uploadResource, e));

              final result = await Future.wait(tasks);
              
              // all tasks done, so we can handle result
              print('result: $result');
            },
          ),
```

Output:

```
flutter: _uploadResource for test 1
flutter: upload for test 1
flutter: _uploadResource for test 2
flutter: upload for test 2
flutter: _uploadResource for test 3
flutter: upload for test 3
flutter: getDownloadableLinkFor for 1011445077
flutter: getDownloadableLinkFor for 504475879
flutter: getDownloadableLinkFor for 130319434
flutter: result: [test 1, 1011445077, :hash_1011445077, test 2, 504475879, :hash_504475879, test 3, 130319434, :hash_130319434]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I believe this will wait with the upload until all resizing is done. Resizing is also time consuming operation and this sort of defies the purpose of returning the resized images in a Stream. Also I don't see a point to do `compute()` on a basically I/O operation, since I believe it will internally process in an isolate internally.

Comment: Yes, this code will wait for image resizing(like a code in the accepted answer). The point why I use compute() function - to start uploading your images simultaneously because in your code they upload one by one. And yes I/O operations are handled by an internal thread pool, but in your code, to start new uploading you have to wait for the previous one. I thought when you wrote "...as ImageResizer does not need to wait for the upload to complete to yield another value" you mean it. @LukasNevosad